# Getting counts of two items of same column in single table

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I am developing a site, which has both desktop and mobile customers. for an analysis, i want to know whether user accessing my site through desktop or mobile device, for that i am having one table in database which has several columns for storing user's device details. In that i have one column called IsMobile, in that i am storing true/false based on user's device. Now i want to get the count of true and false using linq query.

I am using below code.

```
 public IList<IsMobile> IsMobile(DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate)
    {
        var isMobile = (from d in _db.UserDeviceDetail
                        where ((d.CreatedOn.Month >= fromDate.Month && d.CreatedOn.Day >= fromDate.Day && d.CreatedOn.Year >= fromDate.Year) || (d.CreatedOn.Month <= toDate.Month && d.CreatedOn.Day <= toDate.Day && d.CreatedOn.Year <= toDate.Year))
                        group d by d.IsMobile into g 
                        select new IsMobile
                        {
                            Yes = g.Count(n => n.IsMobile == true),
                            No = g.Count(n => n.IsMobile == false)
                        }).ToList();

        return isMobile;
    }
```

I am getting proper count details, but with two list item one for counting Yes and another for counting No, instead i want to get single list item, by counting both yes and no at a time

As it is:
     {Yes 20; No  0}
     {Yes  0; No 10}

How should be: 
     {Yes 20; No 10}

I am new to linq query, please tell what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Please clarify, do you want the sum of Yes + No?  Your example solution seems to match your current code.

Comment: Whats the problem with your code?

Comment: I am getting two list item at first it counting for yes alone and next it counting for no alone, instead i want to count both yes and no at same time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grouping is what makes LINQ to create two items instead of one.
It separates whole set of items into certain number of sub-sets each processed separately.

Your query without grouping should do the trick.

**UPD**: following query should return list with one IsMobile item. It can be simplified if just one item can be returned instead of a list:

```
var isMobile = (from d in _db.UserDeviceDetail 
                        where ((d.CreatedOn.Month >= fromDate.Month && d.CreatedOn.Day >= fromDate.Day && d.CreatedOn.Year >= fromDate.Year) || (d.CreatedOn.Month <= toDate.Month && d.CreatedOn.Day <= toDate.Day && d.CreatedOn.Year <= toDate.Year)) 
                        select d).ToList(); 
return new List<IsMobile>(){
            new IsMobile{ 
                Yes = isMobile.Count(n => n.IsMobile == true), 
                No = isMobile.Count(n => n.IsMobile == false)}
            };
```

Comment: Without group, how will i get the count?

Comment: I may count using d, but i want to assign result to my model object property Yes and No, that how will i do without grouping? i don't want to use new variables

Comment: edited answer to show how I understand it. If this doesn`t correspond with your question, please clarify how IsMobile instance should be returned

Comment: What you understood is right only. I already tried as you mentioned above, it showing me error as UserDeviceDetail  doesn't contain definition for count

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to select a `IList<IsMobile>` at all when you just want to know how many items have `IsMobile == true` and how many have `IsMobile == false`?

I would return a `Tuple<int, int>` instead:

```
public Tuple<int, int> mobileCounts(DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate)
{
    var inTime = _db.UserDeviceDetail.Where(d=> (d.CreatedOn.Month >= fromDate.Month && d.CreatedOn.Day >= fromDate.Day && d.CreatedOn.Year >= fromDate.Year) || (d.CreatedOn.Month <= toDate.Month && d.CreatedOn.Day <= toDate.Day && d.CreatedOn.Year <= toDate.Year));
    int isMobileCount = inTime.Count(d => d.IsMobile);
    int isNotMobileCount = inTime.Count(d => !d.IsMobile);
    return Tuple.Create(isMobileCount,isNotMobileCount);
}
```

You can access both informations via `Item1` and `Item2` property of the tuple.

Comment: Perhaps you could get a count of both in 1 go using variables defined outside the query?